# Int16 found nill

Tags: swift, if-statement, int, uialertcontroller

This IBAction brings up a UIAlertController with two text boxes. One box for name and one for age. I'm trying to make it so that the user does not have to enter their age if they don't want to. right now if they don't enter their age the app crashes right by the `person.age = Int16(points!)!`line saying "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". I am trying to use an if else statement stop this. What am I missing though?

```
   @IBAction func addRowBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add Person", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Task"
        }
        alert.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Points"
            textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
        }
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "post", style: .default) { (_) in
            let name = alert.textFields?.first!.text!
            let age = alert.textFields?.last!.text!
            if name != nil && age != nil {
                let person = Person(context: PersistenceServce.context)
                person.name = name
                person.age = Int16(age!)!
                PersistenceServce.saveContext()
                self.people.append(person)
                self.table.reloadData()

            }
             if name != nil && age == nil {
                let person = Person(context: PersistenceServce.context)
                person.name = name
                person.age = 0
                PersistenceServce.saveContext()
                self.people.append(person)
                self.table.reloadData()
            }
        }
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: that... is a lot of force unwrapping. You should read the Swift language guide, and learn how to properly handle optionals.

Answer (score 1):

For avoiding unwrap problems I would advise you to do it like that:

```
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "post", style: .default) { (_) in
        if let ageString = alert.textFields?.last?.text,
            let age = Int16(ageString),
            let name = alert.textFields?.first?.text {
            let person = Person(context: PersistenceServce.context)
            person.name = name
            person.age = age
            PersistenceServce.saveContext()
            self.people.append(person)
            self.table.reloadData()
        } else if let name = alert.textFields?.first?.text {
            let person = Person(context: PersistenceServce.context)
            person.name = name
            person.age = 0
            PersistenceServce.saveContext()
            self.people.append(person)
            self.table.reloadData()
        }
}
```